# F1Score from torchmetrics is not calculated correctly when using Average Meter pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, torchmetrics

I am using AverageMeter to calculate and sum the f1 score but it doesn't calculate correctly after each epoch is finished (or after evaluation).
I used torchmetric to calculate the f1core.

```py
from time import time
import torch
import tqdm

from utils import TBLoggerBuilder, setup_logger
import os
import numpy as np
from models.metrics import get_metric
from utils.average_meter import AverageMeter
from logging import Logger
from models.utils import save_model_check_points, save_model, best_model, early_stopping_model, init
from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryConfusionMatrix
from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryStatScores
import pandas as pd
import torchmetrics

def evaluation(conf,
               model, criterion, val_loader, device,
               inference, debug
               ):
    print('\nValidating...')
    confmat = BinaryConfusionMatrix()
    stats = BinaryStatScores()
    model.eval()  # Optional when not using Model Specific layer

    y_pred = []
    y_true = []
    
    f1_score = torchmetrics.classification.BinaryF1Score()
    loss_avg = AverageMeter(name='loss')
    f1_avg = AverageMeter(name='f1')

    with torch.no_grad():
        with tqdm.tqdm(val_loader, unit="batch") as tepoch:
            for image, target in tepoch:
                # Transfer Data to GPU if available
                image = image.to(device)
                target = target.to(device)
                # out = model(image)['out']
                # if unet == true => remove ['out']
                out = model(image)
                # Calculate Loss
                target = target.unsqueeze(1)
                target = target.float()
                loss = criterion(out, target)
                # Calculate Loss
                loss_avg.update(loss.item(), image.size(0))

                f1 = f1_score(out.cpu(), target.cpu())
                f1_avg.update(f1.item())
                y_pred.extend(out)  # Save Prediction
                y_true.extend(target)

                tepoch.set_postfix(loss=loss_avg.avg,
                                   f_score=f1_avg.avg)
                if debug:
                    break

        if inference:
            probs = torch.sigmoid(torch.tensor(y_pred))
            predicted_vals = probs > 0.5
            ground_truth_vals = [False if i == 0 else True for i in np.array(y_true)]
            df_result = pd.DataFrame({
                'prediction': np.array(y_pred),
                'predicted_probs': np.array(probs),
                'ground_truth': np.array(y_true),
                'predicted_vals': np.array(predicted_vals),
                'ground_truth_vals': np.array(ground_truth_vals),
            })
            df_result.to_csv('../outputs/results.csv')

        y_pred = torch.tensor(y_pred)
        y_true = torch.tensor(y_true)

        print(f'\nConfusionMatrix: \n{confmat(y_pred, y_true).cpu().numpy()}')
        stats_scores = stats(y_pred, y_true)
        print(f'\ntp: {stats_scores[0]}, fp: {stats_scores[1]},'
              f' tn: {stats_scores[2]}, fn: {stats_scores[3]},'
              f' sup: {stats_scores[4]}')

        print(f1_score(y_pred,y_true),f1_avg.avg)
        return loss_avg.avg, f1_avg.avgF


def train_one_epoch(conf, epoch, model, optimizer, criterion, train_loader, device, debug):
    model.train()
    # f1_score = get_metric(conf=conf.metric)
    f1_score = torchmetrics.classification.BinaryF1Score()
    loss_avg = AverageMeter(name='loss')
    f1_avg = AverageMeter(name='f1')
    with tqdm.tqdm(train_loader, unit="batch") as tepoch:
        tepoch.set_description(f"Epoch {epoch}")
        for image, target in tepoch:
            # Transfer Data to GPU if available
            image = image.to(device)
            target = target.to(device)

            # Forward Pass
            # out = model(image)['out']
            # if unet == true => remove ['out']
            out = model(image)

            # Find the Loss
            target = target.unsqueeze(1)
            target = target.float()
            loss = criterion(out, target)
            # Calculate Loss
            loss_avg.update(loss.item(), image.size(0))
            # Clear the gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # Calculate gradients
            loss.backward()
            # Update Weights
            optimizer.step()

            f1 = f1_score(out.cpu(), target.cpu()).item()
            f1_avg.update(f1)
            tepoch.set_postfix(loss=loss_avg.avg,
                               f_score=f1)
            if debug:
                break
        return loss_avg.avg, f1_avg.avg


def fit(conf,
        model,
        optimizer,
        scheduler,
        criterion,
        train_loader,
        val_loader,
        start_epoch=0,
        device='cpu',
        logger: Logger = None):
    tb_logger = TBLoggerBuilder(cfg=conf.base).setup()

    model_check_point_path = conf.base['model_check_point_path']
    best_model_path = conf.base['best_model_path']

    epochs, debug, early_stopping, checkpoint_step, best_loss = init(
        cfg=conf)
    model = model.to(device)

    if logger is not None:
        logger.info("\nStart training\n")

    start_training_time = time()
    for e in range(start_epoch, epochs):
        start_training_epoch_time = time()
        train_losses_avg, train_f_score_avg = train_one_epoch(conf=conf,
                                                              epoch=e,
                                                              model=model,
                                                              optimizer=optimizer,
                                                              criterion=criterion,
                                                              train_loader=train_loader,
                                                              device=device,
                                                              debug=debug)
        if tb_logger is not None:
            tb_logger.log(log_type='criterion/training', value=train_losses_avg, epoch=e)
            tb_logger.log(log_type='f_score/training', value=train_f_score_avg, epoch=e)

        end_training_epoch_time = time() - start_training_epoch_time
        print('\n')
        if logger is not None:
            logger.info(
                f'Training Results - [{end_training_epoch_time:.3f}s] Epoch: {e}:'
                f' f_score: {train_f_score_avg:.3f},'
                f' Loss: {train_losses_avg:.3f}\n')

        # validation step
        start_validation_epoch_time = time()
        val_losses_avg, val_f_score_avg = evaluation(conf=conf,
                                                     model=model,
                                                     criterion=criterion,
                                                     val_loader=val_loader, device=device,
                                                     inference=False,
                                                     debug=debug)
        if tb_logger is not None:
            tb_logger.log(log_type='criterion/validation', value=val_losses_avg, epoch=e)
            tb_logger.log(log_type='f_score/validation', value=val_f_score_avg, epoch=e)

        end_validation_epoch_time = time() - start_validation_epoch_time
        if logger is not None:
            print('\n')
            logger.info(
                f'validation Results - [{end_validation_epoch_time:.3f}s] Epoch: {e}:'
                f' f_score: {val_f_score_avg:.3f},'
                f' Loss: {val_losses_avg:.3f}\n')

        # early stopping
        early_stopping, stop = early_stopping_model(epoch=e,
                                                    best_loss=best_loss,
                                                    val_loss=val_losses_avg,
                                                    early_stopping=early_stopping)
        if stop:
            break

        # model check points
        checkpoint_step = save_model_check_points(path=model_check_point_path,
                                                  checkpoint_step=checkpoint_step,
                                                  epoch=e,
                                                  model=model,
                                                  optimizer=optimizer,
                                                  scheduler=scheduler,
                                                  loss=criterion,
                                                  avg_loss=train_losses_avg)
        # apply scheduler
        if scheduler:
            if conf.scheduler['name'] == 'reduce_lr_on_plateau':
                scheduler.step(val_losses_avg)
            else:
                scheduler.step()

            if logger is not None:
                logger.info(f"Current learning rate is {optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']}")
            if tb_logger is not None:
                tb_logger.log(log_type='lr', value=optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'], epoch=e)

        # save best model
        if best_model_path:
            best_loss = best_model(model=model, best_loss=best_loss,
                                   val_loss=val_losses_avg, path=best_model_path)

        if tb_logger is not None:
            tb_logger.flush()

        if debug:
            break
        # end of epocha

    end_training_time = time() - start_training_time
    print(f'Finished Training after {end_training_time:.3f}s')
    if tb_logger is not None:
        tb_logger.close()
```

this is the Averagemeter class

```py
class AverageMeter(object):
    """Computes and stores the average and current value"""

    def __init__(self, name, fmt=':f'):
        self.name = name
        self.fmt = fmt
        self.val = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.sum = 0
        self.count = 0

    def reset(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.sum = 0
        self.count = 0

    def update(self, val, n=1):
        self.val = val
        self.sum += val * n
        self.count += n
        self.avg = self.sum / self.count

    def __str__(self):
        fmtstr = '{name} {val' + self.fmt + '} ({avg' + self.fmt + '})'
        return fmtstr.format(**self.__dict__)
```

The result is for example:

```
Validating...
100%|██████████| 65/65 [01:07<00:00,  1.04s/batch, f_score=0.553, loss=0.0522]

ConfusionMatrix: 
[[520   5]
 [ 14 493]]

tp: 493, fp: 5, tn: 520, fn: 14, sup: 507
tensor(0.9811) 0.5534822574028602
```

As you see, the result in validation progress bar is `f_score=0.553` while the f1score after the end of validation is `tensor(0.9811)`

So, it seems getting average from sum of f1score in batch loop is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by using `f1_score.compute().item()`.
I understand that when we are using [torchmetrics](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/metrics), there is a method that compute the metric on all batches using custom accumulation. So, it doesn't need to use AverageMeter to hold the values and compute the average of scores.

```py
def evaluation(conf,
               model, criterion, val_loader, device,
               inference, debug
               ):
    print('\nValidating...')
    confmat = BinaryConfusionMatrix()
    stats = BinaryStatScores()
    model.eval()  # Optional when not using Model Specific layer

    y_pred = []
    y_true = []
    f1_score: torchmetrics.classification.BinaryF1Score = get_metric(conf=conf.metric).get()
    # f1_score = torchmetrics.classification.BinaryF1Score()
    loss_avg = AverageMeter(name='loss')
    # f1_avg = AverageMeter(name='f1')

    with torch.no_grad():
        with tqdm.tqdm(val_loader, unit="batch") as tepoch:
            for image, target in tepoch:
                # Transfer Data to GPU if available
                image = image.to(device)
                target = target.to(device)
                # out = model(image)['out']
                # if unet == true => remove ['out']
                out = model(image)
                # Calculate Loss
                target = target.unsqueeze(1)
                target = target.float()
                loss = criterion(out, target)
                # Calculate Loss
                loss_avg.update(loss.item(), image.size(0))

                f1_score(out.cpu(), target.cpu())

                y_pred.extend(out)  # Save Prediction
                y_true.extend(target)

                tepoch.set_postfix(loss=loss_avg.avg,
                                   f_score=f1_score.compute().item())
                if debug:
                    break

        if inference:
            probs = torch.sigmoid(torch.tensor(y_pred))
            predicted_vals = probs > 0.5
            ground_truth_vals = [False if i == 0 else True for i in np.array(y_true,dtype=object)]
            df_result = pd.DataFrame({
                'prediction': np.array(y_pred,dtype=object),
                'predicted_probs': np.array(probs,dtype=object),
                'ground_truth': np.array(y_true,dtype=object),
                'predicted_vals': np.array(predicted_vals,dtype=object),
                'ground_truth_vals': np.array(ground_truth_vals,dtype=object),
            })
            df_result.to_csv('../outputs/results.csv')

        y_pred = torch.tensor(y_pred)
        y_true = torch.tensor(y_true)

        print(f'\nConfusionMatrix: \n{confmat(y_pred, y_true).cpu().numpy()}')
        stats_scores = stats(y_pred, y_true)
        print(f'\ntp: {stats_scores[0]}, fp: {stats_scores[1]},'
              f' tn: {stats_scores[2]}, fn: {stats_scores[3]},'
              f' sup: {stats_scores[4]}')

        f1_avg = f1_score.compute().item()
        return loss_avg.avg, f1_avg
```